# Emacs-like keybindings globally

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm trying to emulate behaviour I get from KeyRemap4MacBook on Mac OS X. It lets me remap control-m to Enter, for instance, globally.

Is this possible with X/GNOME? Seems like xmodmap is not suitable for remapping key combinations. I tried xbindkeys to bind control-m to `xdotool key Return`, but it emits control-return. I tried `xdotool keyup control; xdotool key Return; xdotool keydown control` but it stills behaves unpredictably.

Any ideas? Kernel level hacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strugled myself with similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/57207/23326) and discovered `autokey` which is just great:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdekter/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Just put `<enter>` as the phrase and set the shortcut to control-m. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Seems like a good option, but I still can't get C-n, C-m etc. to work reliably...