# Rebind Control-n Control-p

Tags: automation, shortcut-keys

I would like to rebind C-n and C-p in all my applications to send Up and Down.
My brain is just stuck with this shortcuts, and I am tired of always seeing new windows and printing dialogs popping up.

I was thinking about xmodmap, but it looks like it can redefine only one keysim not a combination.

Also tried `xdotool key Up` and `xte 'key Up'` to bind from keyboard shortcuts. It doesn't work properly and requires `sleep 0.2` before the invocation which makes it infeasible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it, [autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) is the way to go.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdekter/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Run the GUI and add new phrase with `<up>` as the script and shortcut  <kbd>Cntrl-p</kbd> .
Also you would like to exclude the emacs window, put `((?<!^emacs).)*$` as filter.